# Android navigation drawer height as height of device screen

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawer

Can you tell me how to make Android navigation drawer height as height of device screen? What file of app should I change and how?

Current drawer view => Desired drawer view

[image: Current drawer view] [image: Desired drawer view]

Comment: This is done with the new Toolbar.